# spring-cloud-config: profile does not work properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am learning `spring-cloud-config` and I would like to use different profiles but I always get back values from the `default` profile.

I have two property files in the git repository and the file with `prod` suffix overrides a key from `default` profile:

- image-service.properties
- image-service-prod.properties

It seems that my config server works fine:

**GET http://localhost:8888/image-service/default:**

```
{"name":"image-service","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":"fb78fe4429a33c266d6eb07a9e482b8fd264dd7c","state":null,"propertySources":
[{"name":"https://bitbucket.org/.../...-configuration.git/image-service.properties","source":{"service.image.hello":"image-common"}}]}
```

**GET http://localhost:8888/image-service/prod**

```
{"name":"image-service","profiles":["prod"],"label":null,"version":"fb78fe4429a33c266d6eb07a9e482b8fd264dd7c","state":null,"propertySources":
[{"name":"https://bitbucket.org/.../...-configuration.git/image-service-prod.properties","source":{"service.image.hello":"image-prod"}},
{"name":"https://bitbucket.org/.../...-configuration.git/image-service.properties","source":{"service.image.hello":"image-common"}}]}
```

I activated `prod` profile in my REST application but always value from the default profile is shown.

**application.properties of the client app:**

```
server.port=8889
spring.application.name=image-service

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

**REST controller of the client app:**

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class EchoController {

    @Value("${service.image.hello}")
    private String hello;

    @RequestMapping("/show")
    @ResponseBody
    public String showConfig() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("image-service: ").append(hello)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
image-service: image-common
```

Log from client app:

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=image-service, profiles=[default], label=null, version=fb78fe4429a33c266d6eb07a9e482b8fd264dd7c, state=null
b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='https://bitbucket.org/.../...-configuration.git/image-service.properties'}]}
c.r.d.springconfig.client.Application    : The following profiles are active: prod
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7ccdc9e7: startup date [Sun Sep 23 22:31:55 CEST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7fd618b5
o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=51790958-c0a2-3d61-91d6-a8dcd5395c7e
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf37cae6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8889 (http)
```

It seems I missed something but I can not see what.

Comment: It needs to go in bootstrap.properties

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That was the problem! Now it work fine.

Comment: It is a little bit confused why I need to have two configuration files: application.properties and bootstrap.properties. Maybe the guys from spring team can merge together theese configs.

Comment: I am from the spring team

Comment: @zappee can u post ur answer by showing application.properties and bootstrap.properties. Me also having the same issue.